# based on number property and moving the strings to the last

Tags: javascript

I am doing Sorting based on `GAN`. If it is not a Number I want to display it at the end

The order should be **30, 20, NAN**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var empJson = [{
      "userId": "rirani",
      "jobTitleName": "Developer",
      "GAN": 20
    },
    {
      "userId": "nirani",
      "jobTitleName": "Developer",
      "GAN": "NAN"
    },
    {
      "userId": "thanks",
      "jobTitleName": "Program Directory",
      "GAN": 30
    }
  ];

  var newEmpSortedJSON = empJson.sort(function(a, b) {    
    return b.GAN - a.GAN;
  });

  console.log(newEmpSortedJSON)

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 20em
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.addressfinder.co.nz/assets/v2/widget.js"></script>

<label for="search_field">Address</label>
<input type='text' class='address_field' />
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6v9Lk1s2/1/)

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 4):

You could take the delta of `isNaN` first and then sort by the delta of the values.

```js
var empJson = [{ userId: "rirani", jobTitleName: "Developer", GAN: 20 }, { userId: "nirani", jobTitleName: "Developer", GAN: "NAN" }, { userId: "thanks", jobTitleName: "Program Directory", GAN: 30 }];

empJson.sort((a, b) => isNaN(a.GAN) - isNaN(b.GAN) || b.GAN - a.GAN);

console.log(empJson);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You want to subtract a boolean from another boolean? That's a bit obscure, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

`Boolean(NaN)` is falsy, use the `+` to cast the value to a number and `||` ( OR ) operator to use `0` if it is `NaN` :

```js
var empJson = [
  {
    userId: "rirani",
    jobTitleName: "Developer",
    GAN: 20
  },
  {
    userId: "nirani",
    jobTitleName: "Developer",
    GAN: "NAN"
  },
  {
    userId: "thanks",
    jobTitleName: "Program Directory",
    GAN: 30
  }
];

var newEmpSortedJSON = empJson.sort(function(a, b) {
  return ( +b.GAN || 0 ) - ( +a.GAN || 0 );
});

console.log(newEmpSortedJSON);
```

Comment: what if negative or zero values should come first?

Answer (score 2):

You can force NaN to be last with a simple condition check. Something like so

```js
var empJson = [{
    "userId": "rirani",
    "jobTitleName": "Developer",
    "GAN": 20
  },
  {
    "userId": "nirani",
    "jobTitleName": "Developer",
    "GAN": "NAN"
  },
  {
    "userId": "thanks",
    "jobTitleName": "Program Directory",
    "GAN": 30
  }
];

var newEmpSortedJSON = empJson.sort(function(a, b) {
  return isNaN(b.GAN) ? -1 : b.GAN - a.GAN;
});

console.log(newEmpSortedJSON)
```

Comment: Negative value should not comes first

Answer (score 1):

Just need to flesh out your comparison function, like so:

```
if (isNaN(a.GAN) == true){ return 1 } 
if (isNaN(b.GAN) == true){ return -1 }
return b.GAN - a.GAN
```

Comment: `if (x === true)` is the same as `if (x)`

Comment: I know, this started off as pseudo-code, so I left it like this for clarity.